# Which M2Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I had not faced such a problem before because I have been using Spring Tool Suite, which reduces my stress by straightening out my eclipse life-style and conflicts.

However for some reason, I am now attempting to setup Juno without the convenience of Spring. I am now attempting to install m2eclipse from market place. Bizarrely, there are two listings for m2eclipse in market place. Which one is the true one?

---

1. **Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (from github) by Redhat**.
   The m2eclipse-wtp project has moved to the Eclipse Foundation. The m2eclipse-wtp plugin is now deprecated in favor of the newer m2e-wtp

   Automatic installation from the marketplace has been suspended. m2eclipse-wtp 0.15.3 can be manually installed from http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/
2. **Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP(Juno) by Eclipse.org**

---

Questions:

1. Are they the same build and distribution but hosted by different organisations? Otherwise, as I asked above, which is the true one?
2. Are they forks and therefore might behave differently? If so, which variance should I subscribe to?
3. "m2eclipse" vs "m2eclipse for wtp" : they are the same thing aren't they? I mean there isn't one generic m2eclipse and another m2eclipse specifically for wtp, right? Is it that "m2eclipse for wtp" is simply a more compulsive way of saying "m2eclipse" and no more should be implied from that?

Answer (score 1):

"m2eclipse for WTP" is not the regular m2eclipse; it's a set of extensions that better integrate Maven with the Eclipse Web Tools Project. If you are using a recent build of Juno (why not Kepler?) then m2eclipse, which is now just named "m2e" should already be installed. If you managed to grab a build of Juno without it preloaded, you can use [this update site](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/).

Comment: I would also recommend using Eclipse Kepler, as the built-in m2e in Kepler is far better than the original one which is too buggy to be useful.